# Core Data: Sub-Entities' Default Value for Inherited Attributes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data, inheritance

Is it possible to use the Core Data interface in Xcode to set a default value for attributes inherited from parent entities?

Example: Artwork entity has attribute "medium", defaults to "clay." The sub-entity Painting is a child of Artwork, but I want the "medium" to default to "oil" or "canvas."

I'd like to avoid doing it in code (awakeFromInsert or elsewhere), but if that's what it takes that's fine with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unfortunately you can only set the parent default to `clay`, but there is no way to set a child default for a parent attribute in the model editor. Therefore, you will *have* to modify your class implementations. It's not that inconvenient, if you think about it.

Comment: I figured as much, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.